# Get data members in Python module, as help() does

Tags: python, introspection, python-module

This Python:

```
data = {}

def f():
    pass

import sys

help(sys.modules[__name__])
```

Prints this:

```
Help on built-in module __main__:

NAME
    __main__

FILE
    /foo/bar.py

FUNCTIONS
    f()

DATA
    data = {}
```

My question is, how can I get a list of "data" objects like the help function does?  I looked at inspect.getmembers() but it returns things I don't want, and writing a predicate for it seems like it should not be necessary.

Comment: Usually, you'd use `dir(module)`, but that's doesn't seem to work on the "current" module in the interactive interpreter.

Comment: @larsmans: the issue with dir(module) is that it returns methods too, not only "data."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read the code behind the `help(module)` implementation: http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/110b38c36a31/Lib/pydoc.py#l1060

It's kind of complicated though....

Comment: Now that is interesting!  They define an "isdata()" method right there that I can probably copy/paste and use with inspect.  Thanks!

Comment: For the impatient: 
`def isdata(object):
    """Check if an object is of a type that probably means it's data."""
    return not (inspect.ismodule(object) or inspect.isclass(object) or
                inspect.isroutine(object) or inspect.isframe(object) or
                inspect.istraceback(object) or inspect.iscode(object))`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [the `locals()` builtin](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#locals) in the global scope.

```
>>> data = {}
>>> locals()
{'__builtins__': <module 'builtins' (built-in)>, '__name__': '__main__', 'data': {}, '__doc__': None, '__package__': None}
```

It's worth noting that you will obviously need to filter out the built-in values, which is easily done:

```
>>> {name: value for name, value in locals().items() if not name.startswith("__")}
{'data': {}}
```

Note that generally any problem you will solve like this will be better solved by using a better data structure.